# Got confused about weight loss in liquid

Tags: fluid-statics, free-body-diagram, density, buoyancy, weight

[image]

Suppose two objects of the same mass but of different densities are dropped on water. The large object (say polypropylene) has a lower density than water and the small one (say stainless steel) has a higher density. As a result, the large ball will be floating and the small one will go inside the water. I can't understand which one will lose more weight? Plastic or iron.

[I took all the materials arbitrarily]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a result, the large ball will be floating and the small one will go
> inside the water. I can't understand which one will lose more weight?
> Plastic or iron.

Neither object "loses" weight. The iron object sinks simply because its density is greater than the density of the surrounding liquid and the plastic object floats simply because its density is less than the density of the surrounding liquid.

Regardless of the size of an object, an object whose density is less than or equal the density of the surrounding liquid will float and an object whose density is greater the density of the surrounding liquid will sink.

The volume $V_L$ of the liquid displaced by the object that floats (and thus equals the submerged volume of the object) will depend on the ratio of the density of the object, $\rho_{o}$, to the density of the liquid $\rho_{L}$, according to

$$V_{L}=\frac{\rho _o}{\rho_L}V_o$$

or

$$\rho_{L}V_{L}=\rho_{o}V_{o}$$

Where $V_{o}$ is the total volume of the object, and where $\rho_{o}\le \rho_{L}$. Note that the left side of the equation is the weight of the volume of liquid displaced by the object and the right side is the weight of the object. The weight of the volume displaced by the object equals the upward buoyant of the water acting on the object.

As long as the upward buoyant force of the water on the object equals the weight of the object the object will float. That's the case for the plastic object. If the buoyant force is less than the weight of the object, the object will sink. That's the case for the iron object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Archimedes' Law tells us that when an object is immersed in a fluid, it will experience an upward, so-called buoyancy force $F_B$ that is equal to the weight of the volume of fluid the object displaces:

$$F_B=\rho Vg$$

where $\rho$ is the fluid's density, $V$ the volume of the object and $g=9.81\mathrm{ms^{-2}}$ the Earth's acceleration.

Whether an object will float or sink will depend on its own weight and the buoyancy force, whichever of the two is largest.

Answer (score 0):

The buoyancy in water,  that is the force which diminishes the weight of the object ist the weight of the water of the same volume V , as the body
so the weight ist diminished by V*1g/cm^3.

Comment: As both of them have the same mass both displacing the same amount of water (Say  V). So the weight loss same for both. Are you saying something like this?

Comment: They have different volumes, so they displace different amounts of water. The displaced volume is equal to the volume of the object submerged in the water.

Comment: @SadatRafi The floating object displaces a volume of water equal to its weight. An object sinks because it *cannot* displace enough water to equal its weight - it is too small/dense. An object that sinks weighs *more* than the water it displaces, so it must displace *less* water than an object of equal weight that floats. Two objects of equal weight, one of which floats and one of which sinks, must displace different volumes *and* weights of water.